# Xorg crash on MSI CX623 notebook

Tags: 10.10, xorg, 64-bit

I have a MSI CX623 laptop and I have installed the Ubuntu 10.10, x64bit version on it.

The problem is after I activated the Nvidia driver from Additional Drivers. After restarting Xorg crashes.

This laptop uses the optimus technology of Nvidia, is this supported?

The full specification of this laptop are here: http://www.msi.com/product/nb/CX623.html#/?div=Specification

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some interesting thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1657660&highlight=optimus

But now my question is: When optimus technology will be supported in ubuntu?